# Issue with div background not spanning over entire section

Tags: html, css

I am very new to HTML and CSS. I have a bunch of code in html that looks like the following:

```css
.content-section {
      background: #ffffff;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      border-radius: 3px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="content-section">
                <div class="media-body">
                    ...Media body
                </div>
            
        <form>
          ...Form
    
        </form>
        <br>
        <div>
        ...
        </div>
    
        <div>
          ...
        </div>
    
        <div>
        ...
        </div>
    
        <div>

        <ul>
        
        <li>...</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    
        <div>
        
        <ul>
        
        <li>...<br></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    
    
        <div>
        <ul>
        ...
        </ul>
        </div>
    
        
    
    </div>
```

For some reason, the white background doesn't span over the entire section. I have list elements in my last div that go past the bottom of the white background.

Comment: Everything works well in the code you provided. Provide a more complete code + css (preferably for a list).

Comment: @s.kuznetsov it looks like you're right. The thing is I don't know what to provide because it all seems so irrelevant to the page. The actual background of the website is blue, but the text spans over the white background onto the blue

Comment: Do you have a lot of code?

Comment: @s.kuznetov About 100 lines, could it have to do with the fact that I have classes on headers within some of the divs? Or is there any other reason why like backgrounds like this stop working?

Comment: Yes, maybe for different reasons. Paste the complete code of the cheml and css here.

Comment: Change the background to any other color so it will be obvious to understand what the main problem is.

Comment: @hashBender, OP says that a white background against a blue background (main). Therefore, it makes no sense to change to another color.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Where is the background color I don't see it. Where is blue coming from? When you run the code snippet what background color do you see?

Comment: @hashBender I just have the setting for all of my pages set to blue